# R Markdown: Putting an image in the top right hand corner of HTML and moving title down

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I would like to put a company logo image in the top right hand side of my R markdown report, and then move the title down, say 3 or 4 cm lower than the default position.  The idea being that it looks like company letterhead.

Could anyone suggest how I could code this in my .Rmd file?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you are doing pdf reports, you should just alter the default TeX template and save it as a new template: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/latex/default.tex

Comment: Looking more for a html solution.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Add this script at the beginning (or somewhere else) of your RMarkdown document:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $head = $('#header');
     $head.prepend('<img src=\"logo.jpg\" style=\"float: right;width: 150px;\"/>')
   });
</script>
```

This will look like

[image]

For the script to work, the image has to be in the same folder as the .Rmd document. You could also give the `<img>`tag a certain `id` and add more precise CSS styling with

```
<style>
  #myLogo {
    float: right;
    width: 120px;
    ...
</style>
```

**Option 2:**

Create an extra HTML file (e.g. extLogo.html) that contains the logo like:

```
<div><img src="logo.jpg" width="200px" align="right"></div>
```

Then modify the YAML header like this:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Martin Schmelzer"
date: "13 Juli 2016"
output: 
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: extLogo.html
---
```

This looks like

[image]

and might need some further margin/padding options...

Answer (score 1):

if you change the img src to a base 64 code (really messy as large size) then the image no longer depends on your local directory and for e.g. you could email some one the html file to use an an interactive report.

base64  encoder:
https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: that's true for option one. no need to do for option 2.  altough option 2 seems to be breaking my floatign tabel of contents