# How to change the color/theme on rmdformats/readthedown?

Tags: r, markdown

I'm generating a report using the `rmdformats` package in R, with the `readthedown` format.

How can I change the default overall color?

[image]

Comment: Can someone add the tag #rmdformats to this question, please?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`rmdformats` author here.

To change the default color for titles and other elements, you have to provide a custom CSS file which redefines the default CSS elements defining color.

If think the following CSS elements should be enough :

```css
#main .nav-pills > li.active > a,
#main .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
#main .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
    background-color: #22983B;
}

#main .nav-pills > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #22983B;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, legend {
    color: #22983B;
}

#nav-top span.glyphicon {
    color: #22983B;
}

#table-of-contents header {
    color: #22983B;
}

#table-of-contents h2 {
    background-color: #22983B;
}

#main a {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,#d64a70,#d64a70);
    color: #c7254e;
}

a:hover {
    color: #3d1308;
}

a:visited {
    color: #3d1308;
}
```

Customize and add this to a `custom.css` file in your `Rmd` file directory, and add `css: custom.css` in your preamble.

Comment: Very helpful! What if I wanted to change the background color of the sidebar?

Comment: I need to add a logo on the sidebar (top or bottom). Is it possible?
Referring to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333691/r-markdown-putting-an-image-in-the-top-right-hand-corner-of-html-and-moving-tit I've added the logo on the body space but, if should be possible insert it on the sidebar, will be cleaner

Comment: Where would I add the css: custom.css in the preamble?

Indented under rmdformats::material:?

Comment: @StevenLockton it would look like this

output: 
  rmdformats::readthedown:
    css: custom.css

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want a separate .css file, you can also add elements in the Rmd file between style tags, e.g., outside of a chunk, near the top:

```html
<style>
p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0px 0px 12px 0px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, legend {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #9F2042;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

@csmontt

add this to juba's example.
Also, inspecting the knitted document will help you greatly on how to target specific aspects.

```
#table-of-contents {
color:orange;
background: grey !important; 
}
```

Comment: this is for css file, at the top, for the accepted answer here.

Comment: Please remeber to add # in order to identify the CSS key: #table-of-contents { .. }

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same "issue". After inspecting the source of html page, I found that the following items in CSS file below are sufficient. In particular, the topleft box backgroung color is customized with `#content h2 {}`.

```
#sidebar {
  background: #5A7B9C;
}

#postamble {
  background:#003366;
  border-top:solid 10px #5A7B9C;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #003366;
}

.subtitle {
  color: #003366;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, legend {
  color: #5A7B9C;
}

#content h2 {
    background-color: #003366;
}
```

Comment: simple and elegant solution, tony. Thanks to you too

Comment: what worked for me to do the `background-color` of the top-left title in `rmdformats 1.0.2` was : 


    ```#sidebar h2 { ... }```


where `#sidebar h2` identified the `h2` in the division with the `sidebar` id.

Answer (score 0):

I had to alter some more selectors. Here I give blues and oranges.
[image]

[blue vignette example - link](https://ferroao.gitlab.io/idiogramfishhelppages)

Look for the github code [here](https://gitlab.com/ferroao/idiogramFISH/-/blob/v2.0.14.dev_styling/vignettes/css/mystyle_rmdformats.css?ref_type=heads)