# How can I put a logo in Header of Rmarkdown pdf document?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to have a logo image insert to the header and make it in the right hand side of the file.

```
---
title: "My title"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{titling}
- \pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo.png}}
- \posttitle{\end{center}}
output: 
  pdf_document
---
```

This is the output and what I expected:

[image: output with logo]

Also, how to bold the text in the title chunk?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert a logo in upper right corner of R markdown html document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009788/insert-a-logo-in-upper-right-corner-of-r-markdown-html-document)

Comment: @divibisan thanks for your comment. I am not sure is it because I am having a pdf file instead of a html so it doesn't work.