# How do I add custom logo in navbar title field in rmarkdown?

Tags: html, css, r-markdown

I would like to add a custom logo in the navbar title field section. I tried adding an html script and it worked, but the logo image did not fit inside the navbar kindly — the logo was pushed off by margins, and the menu texts overlapped the logo, etc.

```
name: "my-website"
output_dir: .
navbar:
  title: "I want to add custom logo here"
  left:
- text: "Home"
```

Comment: Could you post a working minimal rmarkdown document.

Comment: Maybe you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333691/r-markdown-putting-an-image-in-the-top-right-hand-corner-of-html-and-moving-tit

Comment: Thank you to both. Martin's answer works with me ; )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I fiddled me a site myself. This is working for me:

```
name: "my-website"
navbar:
  title: "<img id=\"logo\" style=\"width: 30px;\" src=\"dog.gif\" />"
  left:
    - text: "Home"
      href: index.html
    - text: "About"
      href: about.html
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! I got it to work as well. Perhaps I am asking too much, but is there a way to ignore the margins?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by margins? The space below and above the image?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer yes. If we choose width too large it seems there is an incompressible margin above the image

Answer (score 6):

You can specify that on the YAML. For example, if using flexdashboard:

```
---
title: "My Website"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: flatly
    logo: LOGO.png
---
```

*Note that no scaling is performed on the logo image, so it should fit exactly within the dimensions of the navigation bar (48 pixels high for the default "cosmo" theme, other themes may have slightly different navigation bar heights).*